# grunt-contrib-jshint - error was used before it was defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, jshint

I have this problem when i use Grunt-jshint.

i have an Angular app, and i define my controller or directive as:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('beerFormController', beerForm_controller);

beerForm_controller.$inject = ['$scope'];

function beerForm_controller($scope) {
    var vm_main = this;
    vm_main.smsCgHijo = 'some text here';
}
```

and this is the error that i have after start my grunt task:

```
Running "jshint:files" (jshint) task
Linting app/js/directives/beerForm/beerForm_controller.js...ERROR
[L7:C29] 'beerForm_controller' was used before it was defined.
```

**Can somebody help me ?**

**What is problem?**... Thanks

Comment: I don't know angular, but jshint complains because you gave the object 'beerForm_controller' the property '$inject' and only afterwards do you create the object 'beerForm_controller' itself. Maybe switch those two statements?

Comment: i done too, but the problem continue, i write latedef: 'nofunc' but the error continue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem, as stated by the message, is that you've used the `beerForm_controller` function before it appears in the source. This is not actually a problem because function declarations are hoisted but it violates the default JSHint style guide.

You can tell JSHint to allow that style by setting the `latedef` option to `nofunc`.

Comment: I'm using this GRUNT VERSION (grunt-cli v0.1.13 - grunt v0.4.5) and on my jshint task, the option --> latedef:'nofunc' , say the i continue with the same error. How could be resolved?

Thanks